# Adb can't detect android devices in Max OSX 10.7.2

Tags: android, debugging, storage, adb

I installed android sdk but adb can't detect android devices

```
% adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 

%
```

I tried and conformed some following methods and conditions to solve this problem.

- Environment consists Mac OSX Lion and NEC N-06C(android).
- SystemProfiler displaies N-06C information(Product ID, Vendor ID and so on).
- I added Vendor ID to .android/adb_usb.ini and restarted adb. But this change had no influence.
- EasyTether isn't installed.(/System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext doesn't exist)
- This Mac can't detect this android as storage too.
- Another Mac(Snow Leopard) can detects device as storage or debug mode.

I searched some similar situations, these are related to EasyTether or editing and restarting adb_usb.ini. I have tried them and couldn't solve this problem. And, I feel this problem that Mac can't detect as storage is strange.

Does someone know what this problem is?

Comment: check cable, try on different usb port.

Comment: This is off subject, but I highly encourage you to use linux as your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.
This problem is specific between Lion and N-06C Medias.
http://8kpixel.blogspot.com/2011/08/mac-os-x-lionn-06c-mediasadb.html#

Thank you.